# Mudar "com.example" de uma aplicação android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-eclipse

Estou a tentar meter uma aplicação na Playstore, mas aparece o seguinte erro:
"Tem de utilizar um nome de pacote diferente, porque "com.example" é restrito."

O que acontece é que já alterei o nome da package e continua o mesmo erro.

Está aqui um print do código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inicialmente a package tinha o nome "com.example..." e alterei para "teste.example...". E fiz o rename em todo o código. Mas na imagem, na linha 3, a alteração não aconteceu e se alterar manualmente, começa a dar erro no código. Como posso resolver esta situação?

Comment: penso que o problema está na pasta gen, pois existe uma package com esse nome e não deixa alterar para outro, ou seja, se alterar o nome ele volta a gerar uma package nova com o nome antigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema do seguinte modo:

1. Abri um ficheiro com o notepad++
2. Fiz procurar em todos os ficheiros por "com.example" e substitui por outro nome
3. Fiz salvar alterações e funcionou

Comment: Na verdade você nem precisaria sair renomeando tudo, bastava alterar ou inserir o ID da aplicação no AndroidManifest.xml pois ele que é considerado na verificação sobre o .apk.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa mudar o "package" no Manifest.

Se estiver no Eclipse recomendo fazer o seguinte:

1. Botão direito do mouse no projeto
2. Android Tools
3. Rename Application Package